# Sort items inside <td>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there any method I can use so I can sort the elements inside a .

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td><span class="box">1</span></td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            <td><span class="box">2</span></td>
            <td>Some other text</td>
            <td>Some other text</td>
            <td>Some other text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is so I can sort the two boxes across the `<tr>` but keep them inside the `<td>`

You can see my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/JcjAV/1/

[EDIT] updated the fiddle url, so show before and after sorting

Comment: Sorting by tr#id?  It looks like it's already sorted.  If something else... you never said what values you're sorting them by.

Comment: The span.box should be sorted, but can only be sorted inside the first td in each tr

Comment: I'm still not following how you sort one item.  What does it look like unsorted, and what does it look like after it's properly sorted?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to show before and after sorting http://jsfiddle.net/JcjAV/1/

Comment: So 1-2-3-4 is unsorted, but 2-4-1-3 is sorted?  What kind of sort is that?

Comment: Its user sorted, hence using jquery-ui sortable tags :)